# GetConstructors vs. _baseType.GetMethod("GetConstructorImpl", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, constructor, getmethod

Is there a difference in c# / .net 4.5.1 between `TYPE.GetConstructor(...)` and `TYPE.GetMethod("GetConstructorImpl", ...)`?

I've always used the first solution and seen the second one in an external library.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Type.GetConstructor()` (with all its overloads) are the public methods (non-virtual) of the `Type` class that are used to search for a constructor. They internally call the `Type.GetConstructorImpl()` that is a `protected abstract` method that is implemented by the subclasses of `Type` (normally `RuntimeType`). You shouldn't use `Type.GetConstructorImpl()` (and note that you normally can't... It is protected). The `Type.GetConstructor()` code is very simple and only does some parameter checking before calling the `Type.GetConstructorImpl()`. You can easily check this by taking a look at the [reference source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/type.cs#L405). I don't know why your library is using `GetConstructoImpl()`.

Comment: Thanks, that answers by question!

Comment: Switched from GetConstructorImpl to GetConstructor and everything works as expected!